# How to run custom code around the execution of an overriden method?

Tags: java

I want to run custom code around the execution of an overriden method, such that I can swap/alter the original parameters and return value. Specifically, I need to:

1. Intercept the method execution and swap the original parameter with different one.
2. Resume the execution of the original method by passing the swapped parameter.
3. Swap the return value from the original method invocation with a custom function.

Assume I have this superclass:

```java
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public abstract Object foo(final Object obj);
}
```

And this subclass:

```java
public class SubClass {
    @Override
    public Object foo(final Object obj) {
        return "bar" + obj.toString();
    }
}
```

I'd like add a hook to `foo` method execution for all instances of `SubClass`, such that the resulting execution mimics something like:

```java
public class SubClass {
    @Override
    public Object foo(Object obj) {
        final Object swappedObj = beforeExecution(obj);

        // Notice that original code now consumes swapped param
        final Object returnValue = _foo_original_code(swappedObj);

        return afterExecution(returnValue);
    }

    private Object _foo_original_code(final Object obj) {
        return "bar" + obj.toString();
    }
}
```

**How can I achieve this easily?**

I'm looking for options other than using Template Method design pattern. I know Spring Framework supports AOP but I wanted to know if there are other (easier) ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this in the past to accomplish what you're trying to do, but this does create an additional method.  The additional method gives you additional overriding flexibility.

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    public abstract Object doInternal(final Object obj);
    
    public Object doBefore(Object obj) {
        // default implementation
        return obj;
    }
    
    public Object doAfter(Object obj) {
        // default implementation
        return obj;
    }
    
    public Object doWork(Object obj) {
        obj = doBefore(obj);
        obj = doInternal(obj);
        obj = doAfter(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{

    @Override
    public Object doInternal(Object obj) {
        // do specific work here
        return null;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that too, but I didn't like that the names of the methods differ. Potentially there is another way

Comment: You could consider implementing InvocationHandler and making a dynamic proxy. - https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for.